# awk + match string after "=" seperator

Tags: awk

I have problem with the following awk syntax

```
    echo " param1 param2 param3 = param1 AA , AB , AC , AD  "  | awk -F"=" '$2~/AA|AB|AC|AD/{print "passed"}'
```

the awk print passed , but its not shuld be because after "=" I have param1 and not "AA" or AB" etc

the target of the awk is to print passed only if the string after "="
is AA OR AB OR AC OR AD

and if I have something else after "=" then its not should print passed

how to fix the awk syntax?

lidia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `=`, you have the string `param1 AA , AB , AC , AD`. Your awk expression accepts any string that *contains* `AA` or `AB` or `AC` or `AD`. If you want these words to appear at the beginning of the field, you need to anchor the pattern (start it with `^` to match only at the beginning, finish it with '$' to match only at the end). For example the following expression requires the field to be only one of the specified words, possibly with spaces before and after:

```
$2 ~ /^ *(AA|AB|AC|AD) *$/
```

Comment: Better, more complete answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

This awk expression to search for AA at the beginning of the field is ^AA, or to allow zero or more spaces between = and the AA, it is ^ *AA, so this expression ought to only print passed if the first term after the = is AA OR BB OR AC OR AD preceded by zero or more spaces.

```
awk -F"=" '$2~/^ *AA|^ *AB|^ *AC|^ *AD/{print "passed"}'
```